# Query based on multiple rows and multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**Database : Azure SQL server  2019, .net core 3.0**

I'm using stored procedure for querying data.

```
--Table Structure

 create table yourtable 
    (
        id int,
        class int,
        islab bit,
        isschool bit
    );
                        
    

insert into yourtable 
values (1, 1, 1, 1),
       (1, 2, 1, 1),
       (1, 3, 1, 1),
       (2, 1, 1, 0),
       (2, 2, 1, 1),
       (2, 3, 1, 1)
```

Now if I want a query to return all unique Id's where `class = 1 and 2` and `islab = 1` and `isschool = 1`, it should return only Id =1 because

a) `Id=1` has both classes `i,e (1,2)` and in both classes `islab = 1` and `isschool = 1`

b) `Id=2`  is not true for this condition because in `classes 1` value for `isschool = 0`

Can you help me write this query? Currently I'm getting all row for input classes than in c# using list check all conditions. It's working but I want do all in SQL

Also I think using `cursor` in stored procedure I can have same result as in C# but in C# it's easy as we have `Collection` and various methods like `intersect` between lists and so on.

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: Just want help in query

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983) What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work? When you researched for the solution, what about the articles you found didn't you understand?

Comment: Currently I'm getting classes as comma separeted and then sending to c# and doing this check there. But i want do all in SQL

Comment: I search the artcles but didn't find any thing close to it

Comment: Are you sure you';re using SQL server too? `bool` isn't a valid data type in T-SQL.

Comment: The columns `true` and `false` therefore don't have any context in your `VALUES` clause. I assume they should be `'true'` and `'false'` or `1` and `0`; you should really test your DDL and DML before you post it, as it can really confuse or delay users from answering.

Comment: Please check i have updated the question, I think now question and what am currently doing is clear

Comment: *"Also I think using curson in stored procudure "* This is almost always a bad idea; SQL is a set based language, not a programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `islab` and `isschool` are actually a `bit` (as `bool` doesn't exist in SQL Server), one method would be to use a `HAVING` with conditional aggregation. So, for the first one, you would do the following:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM dbo.yourtable
WHERE islab = 1
  AND isschool = 1
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(CASE class WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) = 1
   AND COUNT(CASE class WHEN 2 THEN 1 END) = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is not clear, but based on your expected output, I think you want a query that, for a given set of classes, finds the ids where there are no records with isschool = 0 or islab = 0. You can do this with a `NOT EXISTS` condition:

```
WITH mytab AS
(
 SELECT *
 FROM yourtable
 WHERE class IN (1,2,3) -- Change this line to get your 3 different outputs
)
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM mytab t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
 SELECT *
 FROM mytab t2
 WHERE t1.id = t2.id
  AND (t2.islab = 0 OR t2.isschool = 0)
)
```

For `class IN (1,2)` this returns id 1.
For `class IN (2,3)` this returns ids 1 and 2.
For `class IN (1,2,3)` this returns id 1.

The CTE limits to the classes we want to consider. The subquery in the `NOT EXISTS` finds ids that should be eliminated because either isschool = 0 or islab = 0.

An alternative way of doing this, using a `LEFT JOIN` instead of the `NOT EXISTS` condition is:

```
WITH mytab AS
(
 SELECT *
 FROM yourtable
 WHERE class IN (1,2,3) -- Change this line to get your 3 different version
)
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id
FROM mytab t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN mytab t2
 on t1.id = t2.id AND (t2.islab = 0 OR t2.isschool = 0)
WHERE t2.id is null
```